# Wordpress giving 404 error after url change

Tags: wordpress

Just recently setup Wordpress on Server 2016 through IIS. Everything works fine at the defaults, with localhost as the defaults. However, whenever I add bindings to the site, it begins to not work and will give an error.
[Error code is here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sKffw.png)
Permissions seem to be fine, unless I missed an important step.

Anyone have any ideas on how to fix this? I can no longer access via localhost, the IP, or the domain name.

Comment: try Update (save) permalinks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to update Permalink.
go your `Dashboard -> Setting -> permalink` 
click on save change button. Here you can change URL structure for your permalinks and archives.